# How to add some text to each paired number

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, tampermonkey

I'm having a problem with my script. It parses the SVG from the url and sends the data as a log to the console. The string it sends back looks something like this for a example in google's console: `[346,453,346,452,346,452,346,453,346,453,347,453,347,453,347,454,348,454,349,454,350,454,351,454,352,454,353,454,354,454,354,453,355,452,355,453]`

For each pair I need to add this character "[" to the start of the pair and this character "]" at the end of the pair. 
So it will log the data something like: `[[346,453],[346,452],[346,452],[346,453],[346,453],[347,453],[347,453],[347,454],[348,454],[349,454],[350,454],[351,454],[352,454],[353,454],[354,454],[354,453],[355,452],[355,453]]`

Here's what I've tried.

**My function:**

```
const polylines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'));

polylines.map(
pl => pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(
    pair => pair.split(',').map(x=>+x),

   var paired = ("[" + (x=>+x) + "]"), // Tried adding "(x=>+x)" - result huge error.... Can't use a variable there??

console.log("[" + paired + "]")
```

This ended with a error quickly, as I expected.
I just can't seem to find a way to make my script do this... If you can help please do. This is not a duplicate post of any kind. I need this to log in console a specific way which can't be found on other posts here.

**Full script: (current)**

```
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
// Tell the request where the file is.
xhr.open("GET", "http://URLHERE.com/blah.svg");
// Add event handler to process the file once it's been fetched.
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
// Once the text is available, create an XML parser
// and parse the text as an SVG image.
const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
this.responseText.trim(),
"image/svg+xml"
);
// xmlDoc.getElements() returns something Array-like, but not an Array.
// This turns it into an Array.

const polylines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'));

var Lines = (polylines.map(
pl => pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(
    pair => pair.split(',').map(x=>+x),   //<<<< seperates the comma between each split.
    console.log("[" + pl.getAttribute('points') + "]") // Adds the "[", "]" to the front and back and logs the lines.
    )
));
});
xhr.send();
```

Comment: If you want to get array elements in pair, try incrementing by 2 in a conventional for loop. Something like this `for(var i=0; i<polyline.length; i=i+2) {
 console.log(polyline[i], polyline[i+1])
}`

Comment: When it logs in Google's console. I want it to log something like this: ``[[346,453],[346,452],[346,452],[346,453],[346,453],[347,453],[347,453],[347,454],[348,454],[349,454],[350,454],[351,454],[352,454],[353,454],[354,454],[354,453],[355,452],[355,453]]``

Comment: Right now it's logging like: ``[346,453,346,452,346,452,346,453,346,453,347,453,347,453,347,454,348,454,349,454,350,454,351,454,352,454,353,454,354,454,354,453,355,452,355,453]`` in google's console.

Comment: I think you can replace the `var Lines = ...` block, with the above for loop.

Comment: `"272,437 274,437 274,437 275,437 275,437 277,438 277,438 280,439 280,439 281,440 281,440 282,440 283,440 284,440 285,439 286,438 287,438 287,437 287,436 287,435 288,434" ` consider this is the string returned when you call `pl.getAttribute('points')`.

It returned me this
`["272,437", "274,437", "274,437", "275,437", "275,437", "277,438", "277,438", "280,439", "280,439", "281,440", "281,440", "282,440", "283,440", "284,440", "285,439", "286,438", "287,438", "287,437", "287,436", "287,435", "288,434"]`
then you map again like this `.map(arg => console.log('['+arg+']'));`

Comment: :( i want to give up. Here is my current script its still not doing right https://jsfiddle.net/g10L9mcx/1/ I need it to print like this in the console. PLEASE MAN. ``[[346,453],[346,452],[346,452],[346,453],[346,453],[347,453],[347,453],[347,454],[348,454],[349,454],[350,454],[351,454],[352,454],[353,454],[354,454],[354,453],[355,452],[355,453]]`` The way it is now. It prints one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried somthing like this?

```
var result = "";

for(i=0; i>polylines.length; i+8) {
   result = result + "["+polylines.slice(i,i+7)+"],"
   console.log("["+polylines.slice(i,i+7)+"]");
}
```

The SLICE method can get two params, the first one is BEGIN and the second is the END, both are related to the index of your String. But be careful, it will begin to take the letter that is in the BEGIN index to the letter that is in the END-1 index  ie it leaves the index of END back.

```
var exemple = "stackoverflow";

console.log(exemple.slice(5,9));

//console: "over"
```

OBS: The original string/array will not be modified.

You can learn more about this, and the "three S" on: https://medium.com/@jeanpan/javascript-splice-slice-split-745b1c1c05d2

Comment: it was to be yours String [346,453,346,452,346,452,346,453,346,453,347,453,347,453,347,454,348,454,349,454,350,454,351,454,352,454,353,454,354,454,354,453,355,452,355,453]

Comment: Whats the value of polylines after this line "const polylines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'));"?

Comment: Here is my current script it's still not doing right https://jsfiddle.net/g10L9mcx/1/ I need it to print like this in the console: ``[[346,453],[346,452],[346,452],[346,453],[346,453],[347,453],[347,453],[347,454],[348,454],[349,454],[350,454],[351,454],[352,454],[353,454],[354,454],[354,453],[355,452],[355,453]]`` ..    The way it is now. It prints one at a time logging like this: ``[287,436]``

Comment: From that link you can see what I tried to do pretty much. It's just some complicated stuff.

Comment: Please fix the script from that link or my script I posted in my question. I just really want it to print the data like this ``[[346,453],[346,452],[346,452],[346,453],[346,453],[347,453],[347,453],[347,454],[348,454],[349,454],[350,454],[351,454],[352,454],[353,454],[354,454],[354,453],[355,452],[355,453]]``

Comment: That's all I need it to do. Just log it just like that. The closest I can get it to log like that is in my question. That script.

Comment: I want to help you, but i really need to know the exactly value of your constant "polylines" after this line "const polylines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'));", jus make a console.log(polylines) and put it on fiddle, so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g10L9mcx/2/ I've added the ``console.log(polylines)`` This is what it returned in google's console. ``(56) [polyline, polyline, polyline, polyline, polyline, polyline, polyline, polyline, polyline, polyline, polyline]`` I had to remove some of the polylines.. Ran out of characters, but that's all it logs.

Comment: If you need more info please notify me. I'll try my very best. I really need help with this.

Comment: Try this fiddle, then send him back, https://jsfiddle.net/0qs8dgej/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ywk2p5r4/ I've put a video link in it... I've showed a few details of the log with that video. Opening it and scrolling through it a bit. Also gave the URL i'm running the script on.

Comment: ``http://colorillo.com/bxys.inline.svg`` That's the URL i'm running the script on. ``view-source:http://colorillo.com/bxys.inline.svg`` show's the full source of the XML. Idk if this will help, and btw thanks man for even trying to help me. Much respect to you dude. I don't get much help from this site. I think I just ask the questions poorly.

Comment: Try this, https://jsfiddle.net/uca8zgt7/

Comment: Do not worry, this is normal but try to be more specific in asking, do not take too many turns, and clarify well what you have, and what you want. Have a nice day.